# Updating a FieldPermission record produces a INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST error

Tags: profile, permission-sets, fls

I am attempting to update FLS using `FieldPermission` records for profiles and permission sets.  This is working fine for `unmanaged` fields, but for `managed fields` I am getting an error saying that the field does not belong to the object, when I know it does.

I am building a tool that lets user mass edit FLS across profiles and permission sets and everything works fine for unmanaged fields.

**For example, I query this data:**

```sql
SELECT Id, PermissionsEdit, Field, ParentId, PermissionsRead, SobjectType
FROM FieldPermissions
WHERE Field = 'Account.SBQQ__ContractCoTermination__c'
```

**Which returns some records - here is a record returned for a permission set in the org:**

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "type": "FieldPermissions",
    "url": "/services/data/v46.0/sobjects/FieldPermissions/01k2J00005ITcelQAD"
  },
  "Id": "01k2J00005ITcelQAD",
  "PermissionsEdit": true,
  "Field": "Account.SBQQ__ContractCoTermination__c",
  "ParentId": "0PS50000000ZpQ0GAK",
  "PermissionsRead": true,
  "SobjectType": "Account"
}
```

**Then, when I attempt to update this record - for example, sending an update with the following data (or even the same data as Salesforce returned):**

```
{
  "Id": "01k2J00005ITcelQAD",
  "PermissionsEdit": false,
  "PermissionsRead": true,
}
```

**The error response I get is this:**

`INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST:Cannot find Field Account.SBQQ__ContractCoTermination__c for SobjectType Account:--`

**I have tried a few variations with the same error each time:**

1. Insert new record which no existing permissions exist (same error)
2. Use the Durable Id format (e.x. `Account.00N50000004RBWE` which produces the identical error)
3. remove namespace from the field `Account.ContractCoTermination__c` and `Account.SBQQ.ContractCoTermination__c` (I was just trying anything at this point)

Comment: Does your running user have FLS to this field and (if necessary) a license for the managed package?

Comment: My user is system admin (dev org) and does have a user for the managed package.  It is really odd - If no permission exists on a field (which means no FieldPermission record is returned), then I can update the FLS in the SFDC UI and then re-query the FieldPermission record and it shows up - then if I attempt to update the record without even changing any of the fields, it produces the same restricted picklist error.

Comment: @DavidReed - WOW - actually, I double checked and realized I had some other user I was using for testing and the license was NOT assigned. I tried again with a different user and everything worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @davidreed - the user making the change must have a license assigned to the managed package.  Any user, even without the managed package license, can query the `FieldPermission` object and see all records across all packages, but only users with an assigned license can make updates to `FieldPermission` records.

Answer (score 0):

For my custom object, I'm able to create a FieldPermissions to a PermissionSet with the following. Notice SObjectType & Field are needed. Hope this helps!

```
fieldPermissionsParams = {}
fieldPermissionsParams["ParentId"] = '0PSi00000010KnrGAE'
fieldPermissionsParams["SObjectType"] = 'Receipt__c'
fieldPermissionsParams["Field"] = 'Receipt__c.Notes__c'
fieldPermissionsParams["PermissionsEdit"] = true
fieldPermissionsParams["PermissionsRead"] = true
restforceClient.create!('FieldPermissions', fieldPermissionsParams)
```